# Running a mysql query in an external php function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to clean up my code and I was wondering if I can place my mysql query that I call several times into an external php function that I include at the top of the file. Everytime I have tried it I have received an error, so I am wondering if it has something to do with my still being relatively new to php. It all works until I place the code in a new file (functions.php)

Here are some snippets:

This is from the page to be displayed

```
<?php
    retreive_user_data();
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queryobj)) {
        echo $result['about'];
    }
?>
```

And here is the php file I'm including

```
<?php 
    function retrieve_user_data() {                                 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users, editables WHERE users.user = editables.user";
        $queryobj = mysql_query($query);
        return $queryobj;
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's telling me that queryobj is an unidentified variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change;

```
retreive_user_data();
```

To:

```
$queryobj = retreive_user_data();
```

Some other notes:

The mysql functions are depreciated, switch to mysqli.

If you use them, use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` not `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Condense `retrieve_user_data()` to one line:

```
function retrieve_user_data() {                                 
  return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users, editables WHERE users.user = editables.user");
}
```

Your query style is also depreciated. Change it to:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN editables USING user
```

PS. Try to find some more modern tutorials to learn from. Look for use of mysqli - that's a good signal it's reasonably new.